# How to Send Form Content by E-mail and Redirect to a New Window at the same time with "Send" Form Button?

Tags: php, html, forms

Is there a way to send content from form to a email and Redirect to another web adresss?

I have a form in my site and want to receive email with clients data when they submit the form. After click on Send button I want to redirect the user to another page with a video and stuff.

How to do that? I´m actually Using Form action as "mailto".

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
<a href="mailto:abc@abc.com" onclick="window.location.href='newpage.html'">
```

Comment: for redirecting to another web address use full url like  `window.location.href='http://example.com'`

Comment: Please explain your solution too

Comment: bhuwan, Upvoted! 
But the system  returns me the message: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"